# How to take input from JOptionPane and pass it to Process or ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java

I am taking input from the JOptionPane and I want to pass the input taken, to a Process that is going to run a java program and take the input. So, basically what I am trying to say is that I am making a very simple java IDE as a school project and I have to run the java program written by someone in my IDE. Now it may happen that their program wants input. And I am taking that input using JOptionPane and trying to pass it to my IDE for running the program successfully.

Here's my `run()` method that will run their java program:

```
public static void run(String path) throws IOException {
    int dotIndex = path.indexOf(".");
    String code = editorArea.getText();
    String input = "";

    path = path.substring(0, dotIndex);
    if (code.contains("Scanner")) {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter the inputs separated by |, if any:");
    }
    // String[] argss = { "cmd", "/c", "java " + path };
    //ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(argss); //This line does not throw error but it does not show any output too.
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java " + path); //This line throws IOException -> The system cannot find the file specified
    Process process = pb.start();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    writer.write(input + "\n");
    writer.flush();
    String line = "", output = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("i am here" + line);
        output += line;
    }
    reader.close();
    writer.close();

    outputArea.setText(output); //outputArea is an object of JTextArea
}
```

I wrote the above code by referring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427138/how-to-input-in-a-program-running-in-cmd-using-java%20target).

Comment: @Abra yes the ```path``` parameter ends with the extension that's why I found the index of the ```.``` and used ```substring```(in line 1 to 4). Actually, the method is bounded to a button and it gets called at the click of the button.

Comment: @Abra yes you are right

Comment: @Abra the problem is that I don't see anything in ```outputArea```.

Comment: So even if the "code" in your `editorArea` does not contain `Scanner`, when you "run" the code, nothing is displayed in the `outputArea`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me. Note though, that the input read by the `Scanner` is not displayed. Also not that the code utilizes [JEP 330](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) (Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs) which was added in JDK 11.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class IdeRunna implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final Pattern  CLASS_NAME;
    private static final String  RUN = "Run";

    private JFrame  frame;
    private JTextArea  editorArea;
    private JTextArea  outputArea;

    static {
        CLASS_NAME = Pattern.compile("\\bpublic\\s+class\\s+(\\w+)");
    }

    private static String getClassName(String sourceCode) {
        String className = null;
        if (sourceCode != null  &&  !sourceCode.isEmpty()) {
            Matcher matcher = CLASS_NAME.matcher(sourceCode);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                className = matcher.group(1);
            }
        }
        return className;
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case RUN:
                try {
                    runCode();
                }
                catch (Exception x) {
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic, String tooltip) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton("Run", KeyEvent.VK_R, "Run code."));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createEditor() {
        editorArea = new JTextArea(20, 70);
        editorArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorArea);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(new JLabel("EDITOR"));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JScrollPane createOutput() {
        outputArea = new JTextArea(20, 70);
        outputArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(new JLabel("Program Output", SwingConstants.CENTER));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JSplitPane createSplitPane() {
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                                              createEditor(),
                                              createOutput());
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(0.5d);
        return splitPane;
    }

    private String getUserInput(String sourceCode) {
        String input = "";
        if (sourceCode != null  &&  !sourceCode.isEmpty()) {
            if (sourceCode.contains("Scanner")) {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                                                    "Enter the inputs separated by |, if any:");
            }
        }
        return input;
    }

    private void runCode() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String sourceCode = editorArea.getText();
        String className = getClassName(sourceCode);
        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), className + ".java");
        try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
            bw.write(sourceCode);
        }
        String input = getUserInput(sourceCode);
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", path.getFileName().toString());
        Process proc = pb.start();
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes());
        os.flush();
        String progOutput = br.readLine();
        while (progOutput != null) {
            outputArea.append(progOutput);
            outputArea.append("\n");
            progOutput = br.readLine();
        }
        proc.waitFor();
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("IDE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createSplitPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new IdeRunna());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture.

[image: Getting input for Scanner]

And after clicking OK button in `JOptionPane`

[image: After input entered]

Comment: There is a slight problem. Suppose the program written by the user raises an Exception, say ArithmeticException, nothing happens then, meaning the ```outputArea``` remains empty. How to go about this?

Comment: @AyushGupta see method [redirectErrorStream(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream-boolean-) in class `ProcessBuilder`